# Is there a offset between onTouchEvent and onTouchListener?

Tags: android, view, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have developed a game that shoots when player touches the screen by using `onTouchListener` for my custom `SurfaceView` and `Thread`.

But now I want to change the approach and instead of `onTouchListener` I added `onTouchEvent` to the `SurfaceView` o my Activity.

The problem is that I get some kind of offset when I click on the emulator.
Everything is working great, except that offset keeps appearing and I don't understand why.

Also let me mention that my app is running in landscape mode, maybe this is relevant.

I suspect that it isn't working properly because `onTouchListener` was added to the view  and depended on it, but `onTouchEvent` doesn't depend on the view.

Also my view doesn't have any padding or margin properties, it is full-screen view (`fill_parent`).

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: How large is the offset? Is is in x or y direction? Is it always the same value or does it depend on where you click the screen? Does the problem only occur on the emulator or also on real devices?

Comment: When you say you're getting an offset, you mean something like this:
you touch at x = 100, y = 100
but the MotionEvent shows the touch at
x = 100, y = 120

Comment: Yes, offset occurs in x and y ( on y more than x ) and i haven't tested it on a real device, but i have tested it on emulators ( one that comes with eclipse and bluestacks )

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on a real device. In only get an offset in y direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have done my application, and everything works correctly now, but i still do not know what the problem was.**

After lots of debugging of my application the `onTouchEvent` returned random Y values that were always higher than the ones that the `onTouchListener` returned. And i am not sure why this is hapening since my view that recognizes the `onTouchListener` is a full-screen view.

So i figured out a way to get passed this by doing some math.

The first function that the android calls is the `onTouch` method which gives the correct values but just for one touch. I needed it to give right values even on the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` so i noticed that `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is actually doing correctly depending on the first touch recognized by the `onTouchEvent`.

So i just got the coordinate Y from the `onTouch` and the different coordinate with the offset from `onTouchEvent` calculated the difference and in every `onTouchEvent` from there, until the user lifts up their finger, i just subtract that difference and that gives me the correct value.

If anyone else has this problem, and doesn't know how to fix it, here is my code, maybe it will be helpful.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg1) {
    /*you can only touch when the thread is running*/
    if(game.state() != STATE_PAUSE){
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            coordinateX = arg1.getX();
            coordinateY = arg1.getY();
            differenceY = Math.abs(coordinateY - touchedY);
            coordinateY = coordinateY - differenceY;
            shootingIsOkay = true;
            game.setDrawCircle(coordinateX,coordinateY);
        }
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            coordinateX = arg1.getX();
            coordinateY = arg1.getY();
            coordinateY = coordinateY - differenceY;
            shootingIsOkay = true;
            game.setDrawCircle(coordinateX,coordinateY);
        }
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                shootingIsOkay = false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the `onTouch` method that is called from the `onTouchListener` that depends on the view is just simple, here:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    touchedY = arg1.getY();
    return false;
}
```

**If anyone knows how to fix this problem, please post your answer, i am very curious why this is happening**